# Qual a linguagem utilizada no arquivo ".htaccess" do Apache?

Tags: htaccess, característica-linguagem

Por exemplo as seguintes linhas representam qual linguagem :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri_path=$1
```

Comment: Segundo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064504/what-language-are-apache-htaccess-files-written-in Não há um nome específico para a sintaxe como um todo, mas eles são chamados de Diretivas.

Comment: .htaccess é um arquivo de configuração para uso em servidores web rodando o software de servidor Web Apache. Quando um arquivo .htaccess é colocado em um diretório que é por sua vez "carregados através do Apache Web Server", então o arquivo .htaccess é detectado e executado pelo software Apache Web Server.  http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em poucas palavras, é uma "linguagem" específica para configurar o Apache que não tem um nome explícito na documentação, e nem se restringe ao `.htaccess`.

Se trata de uma coleção de [diretivas](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directives.html) que equivalem em grande parte aos parâmetros de configuração do Apache HTTP Server, e a sintaxe está especificamente atrelada à isto.

Como dito no manual do Apache, na seção de [diretivas](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directives.html):

> *They are described using a consistent format, and there is a dictionary of the terms used in their descriptions available.*

Ou seja:

> Elas são descritas usando um formato consistente, e há um dicionário de termos usados em suas descrições.

Em nenhum ponto se dá um nome específico para isto, tudo é tratado genericamente como diretiva.

O `.htaccess` é uma extensão das configurações, e ele existe para ser um facilitador no sentido de você poder mudar parâmetros específicos em diretórios diferentes sem mesmo precisar de acesso à configuração geral.

Ainda, no [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html):

> No geral, arquivos .htaccess usam a mesma sintaxe que os arquivos de configuração principal.

Especificamente sobre o exemplo dado na pergunta, se tratam das diretivas do [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), e neste caso se usam [`RegEx`es](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), ou seja, [Expressões Regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) (mais especificamente PCRE) em certos parâmetros.

Links de interesse:

- **[.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)** no manual do Apache HTTP Server;
- **[mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)** também no manual;
- **[Expressão Regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)** na Wikipedia;